# How to add to User Object Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

I'm new to node so bear with me!

I am working on my auth system. I have login, register and logout done so far. Now I want to update my user in the settings page. How would I go about updating the already added User items such as username, password and email? And most importantly adding new ones such as API Key, and API Secret.

Here is my code:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    apiKey: {
        type: String
    },
    apiSecret: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

My user schema, the api key info is not added on registration. Should it be in the schema or will it be added automatically later?

```
    var newUser = new User({
                username: username,
                email:email,
                password: password
            });
User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log(user);
                    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');

                    res.redirect('/users/login');
                });
```

How I create the new user after verification.

```
router.post('/settings', function(req, res){
    var apiKey = req.body.apiKey;
    var apiSecret = req.body.apiSecret;
    //INSERT api info into DB here
});
```

Where I get the API keys from a form and then want to insert them into the User that is currently logged in. This is where my problem is.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've access to the logged in user in req like `req.user`

```
router.post('/settings', function(req, res) {
    var updateFields = {
        apiKey: req.body.apiKey,
        apiSecret: req.body.apiSecret
    }

    User.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": req.user._id}, {"$set": updateFields}, {"new": true}})
      .exec(function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
           //handle err
          } else {
           //user contains updated user document
          }
      });

});
```

And yes you should keep all the fields you want to insert even in future in the schema. Else they won't insert into database.